# PHP OOP best practices of specifying property to be adjusted

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use a class that determine the salary and number of people with a salary, OOP is new to me and I have gone through plenty of tutorials and examples, but I am not sure if I am using best practices in the following:

```
class quickCalc
{
    private $salary = 0;
    private $person = 0;
    private $person_salary = 0;

    private animal = 0;
    private animal_salary = 0;

    public function addCost($type, $salary)
    {
        $this->$type++;

        $type_two = $type.'_salary';

        $this->$type_two += $salary;
    }

    public function getCount($type)
    {
        return $this->$type;
    }

    public function getCost($type)
    {
        $type = $type.'_salary';
        return $this->$type;
    }

}   

$test = new quickCalc();
$test->addCost('person', 15000);

echo $test->getCount('person'); //1
echo $test->getCost('person'); //10000
echo $test->getCount('animal'); //0
```

So as can be seen, as I add a person, or animal, etc, the related property increases by 1, and the salary value is added to the existing value

What I am not sure of, is if it is best practice to pass the property name through the object, as shown:

```
public function addCost($type, $salary)
{
    $this->$type++;
}
```

or should each property have its own function, such as this:

```
public function addPerson($salary)
{
    $this->person++;
    $this->person_salary++;
}
```

Comment: This question seem better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could alternatively still always _call_ the same method, but use a `switch` statement inside and then run the associated method for said type.

Answer (score 0):

Each property should have its own function. Having a "dynamic" property like this feels weird.

You could however check how [property overload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) works in php. Examples are interesting.

I must add that it looks to me your task should involve an array (or [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)). You can add salaries, then count or compute average etc. with existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, instead of having separate `private` properties use arrays to store individual type and corresponding salary values. Here's an example:

```
class quickCalc{

    private $type = array('person' => 0, 'animal' => 0);
    private $salary = array('person' => 0, 'animal' => 0);

    public function addCost($type, $salary){
        $this->type[$type]++;
        $this->salary[$type] += $salary;
    }

    public function getCount($type){
        return $this->type[$type];
    }

    public function getCost($type){
        return $this->salary[$type];
    }
}   

$test = new quickCalc();
$test->addCost('person', 15000);
echo $test->getCount('person') . "<br />"; // 1
echo $test->getCost('person') . "<br />"; // 15000

$test->addCost('animal', 20000);
$test->addCost('animal', 20000);
echo $test->getCount('animal') . "<br />"; // 2
echo $test->getCost('animal') . "<br />"; // 40000
```

Output:

```
1
15000
2
40000
```